# Jade Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: pug

Why `menuItems` is undefined in the following code?

```
- var menuItems = ["Main","Contacts","About"]
mixin showItems(items)
    ul
        each item in items
            li: a(href="#") #{item}
extend layout
block content
    +showItems(menuItems)
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Weird, this code as it is works for me. (after removing the `extend layout` part). You can check by copy-pasting it [here](http://jade-lang.com/demo/). Makes me think the error must be in the layout

Answer (score 0):

```
- var menuItems = ["Main","Contacts","About"]
mixin showItems(items)
    ul
        each item in items
            li: a(href="#") #{item}
extends layout
block content
    +showItems(menuItems)
```

There is a Typo 'extends layout'