# Syntax error in jade

Tags: pug

```
- var menuItems = ["Main","Contacts","About"]
mixin showItems(items)
    ul
        each item in items
            li: a(href="#") #{item}
extend layout
block content
    +showItems(#{menuItems})
```

I get the following error:

> Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: try `+showItems(menuItems)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283251/jade-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined